# Push Uiview and populate with data

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I'm creating a simple app that stores data into a sqlite database and retrieves data from it. I'm able to store data and I'm also able to populate a UITableView with all the data, showing a field (name) in the prototype cell. What I'm trying to do now is to open a view on tap to show ALL the details. So I did set up a viewController with 3 fields to be filled in, but I don't know how to transfer data between that cell to the new view.

Here's my code:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Inserimento_Esame.h"
#import "Dettagli_Esame.h"

@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize nome,crediti,voto;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, 
YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
@"Esami.sqlite"]];
dataList = [[Data alloc] init:databasePath];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{return YES;}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [dataList getSize];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"nome"];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"voto"];
return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DETTAGLI" sender:indexPath]; 

}





- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DETTAGLI"])  {
    NSLog(@"Dettagli");
    Dettagli_Esame *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath * myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[dataList objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row];
    destination.Dett = itemAtIndex;

 // I THINK I MUST PUT HERE MY MISSING CODE

}
}
@end


EDIT3

#import "Dettagli_Esame.h"

@interface Dettagli_Esame ()

@end

@implementation Dettagli_Esame
@synthesize nome;
@synthesize crediti;
@synthesize voto;
@synthesize Dett;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{[super viewDidLoad];}

EDIT5-6:

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSLog(@"Dettagli Esame");

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,   
YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
@"Esami.sqlite"]];
dataList = [[Data alloc] init:databasePath];
nome.text = [Dett objectForKey:@"nome"];
crediti.text = [Dett objectForKey:@"crediti"];
voto.text = [Dett objectForKey:@"voto"];
NSLog(@"Dettagli Esame: %@", self.Dett);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track.  The information that `destination` needs is the same that you used to populate your cell (actually, you say 3 fields but I'll assume they're all in the same dictionary), so:

```
NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[dataList objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row];
```

Then you need to create a `NSDictionary` property in the `Dettagli_Esame` class and assign it, something like:

```
destination.displayDictionary = itemAtIndex;
```

These lines would go where you indicate "missing code".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my above code,but nothing changed. Dett is a NSDictionary in Dettagli_Esame class

Comment: Almost there, In your view did load method, populate your uitextfields with the entries from your dictionary.

Comment: I tried something,please take a look at my Edit2 points in the source code. I tried adding NSIndexPath * myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[dataList objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row];
    nome.text=[itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"nome"];
    crediti.text=[itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"crediti"];
    voto.text=[itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"voto"]; in viewDidLoad and also in prepareForSegue but nothing changed

Comment: I thought you wanted to show "nome,crediti,voto" in the destination controller.  If that's true, those properties should belong to `Dettagli_Esame` and you would need to move the assignments into **its** `viewDidLoad:`.  (Example: `self.nome.text = [self.Dett objectForKey:@"nome"];`)

Comment: You understood correctly: nome, crediti,vote must go into Dettagli_Esame view controller. I edited my source code, please take a look...

Comment: That looks reasonable.  If the 3 visual fields are hooked up correctly to those 3 properties, I think it should work.  What do you see if you log `Dett`, like `NSLog(@"Dettagli Esame: %@", self.Dett);`?

Comment: I got (null). I edited my code and in this way I can load into Dettagli_Esame the content indexed in the line: NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[dataList objectAtIndex:1]; (one in this case). I think I need something "dynamic" index

Comment: It may be a problem with the order of methods being called.  Try going back to self.Dett and moving the code in Dettagli_Esame from viewDidLoad: to viewDidAppear:.

Comment: We're really close...I edited my code: now Dett contains the right values but they're not shown in the UITextfields. In the UITextfields I see the values coming out from NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[dataList objectAtIndex:0]; line

Comment: That **is** what you're assigning them in "edit 5".  :)  (`nome.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"nome"];
`)